# How to reuse where clause in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to make a query using `EF` and my query looks like the following

```
var users = MyDbc.AspNetUsers.Where
            (
                  d => 
                  (
                      d.UserPlans.Where(m => m.IsActive == 1).FirstOrDefault().PlanId == 2
                      ||
                      (d.UserPlans.Where(m => m.IsActive == 1).FirstOrDefault().PlanId == 3 
                        && d.UserGroups.FirstOrDefault().Group.AdminId == d.Id)
                  )
            );
```

How can I avoid querying UserPlans twice?
in `SQL` I would write the following

```
SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers U INNER JOIN UserPlan UP ON U.Id = UP.UserId 
WHERE UP.IsActive = 1
AND (
PlanId=2 OR (PlanId=3 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Group] WHERE AdminId=U.Id ))
)
```

Comment: That entire Linq query will be translated into one SQL query, so you're not really querying UserPlans twice.

Comment: You can easly check the resulting SQL query with `((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString()`

Comment: I have used profiler to check the query and it seems I have two `outer apply statements of UserPlans `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use built-in query syntax:

```
var users = from user in MyDbc.AspNetUsers
            from plan in user.UserPlans.Where(m=>m.IsActive == 1)
            where plan.PlanId == 2 || plan.PlanId == 3 && ...
```

It is more agile in terms of selecting query time variables. And it is MUCH more readable when your query goes large. For simple queries I personally still use pure LINQ extensions.

**PS**

As *@juharr* mentioned in comment, your query will probably be optimized by SQL provider, so you are good with performance, but readability and fault-resistance of your query is indeed poor.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably pack this into a view or stored procedure (if you need dynamic ids) and load that separately.

```
CREATE VIEW Users
AS   
SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers U INNER JOIN UserPlan UP ON U.Id = UP.UserId 
WHERE UP.IsActive = 1
AND (
PlanId=2 OR (PlanId=3 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Group] WHERE AdminId=U.Id ))
)
GO
```

and then call it in c#...

```
var users = MyDbc.Users.ToList();
```

... like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for this. You can just do both checks straight in the first where.

```
d.UserPlans.Where(m => m.IsActive == 1 && 
(m.PlanId == 2 || (m.PlandId == 3 &&
d.UserGroups.FirstOrDefault().Group.AdminId == d.I)))
```